# Oculus Quest: How to disable casting, video recording, screenshots

Tags: unity, oculus

How can I disable casting, video recording (video capture), and taking photos (screenshots) when developing an Oculus/Meta Quest game.

Answering my own question after spending hours googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/ps-sharing/#sharing-is-on-by-default):

> It is important to note that the sharing features such as casting,
> video recording (video capture), and taking photo (screenshots) are
> enabled for your apps, by default. To disable any sharing features, go
> to [Sharing](https://developer.oculus.com/manage/app/sharing), select an app, and from the Enabled Features list, clear
> the checkbox for the features you do not prefer to share, and click
> Save.

This will work for all platforms, Unity, Unreal, native apps.